# How to install a MySQL plugin with Ansible?

Tags: mysql, database, deployment, ansible, automation

So far we've been using the [Geerlingguy Ansible role](https://github.com/geerlingguy/ansible-role-mysql) for all of our database deployments, but now I'm expanding our usage of it for a new project, and it doesn't seem installing plugins is a supported option. The command I need executed in one way or another in MySQL is

```
INSTALL PLUGIN group_replication SONAME 'group_replication.so';
```

I doubt it's a good idea to even consider gathering facts and using the shell module to actually execute the commands directly, but so far I don't see any other options. Is there anything relevant I haven't spotted? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

I think you could generate an sql file with the **INSTALL PLUGIN** line and use the MySQL [import function of the Ansible mysql_db module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/mysql_db_module.html) to run it.

This might be better than using the shell.

```
- name: Import sql similar to mysql -u <username> -p <password> < file.sql
  mysql_db:
    state: import
    name: DATABASE-NAME
    target: /path/to/import/file.sql
```

Comment: Thanks for the idea! This sounds like a good way of importing the plugin once it's already provisioned to the server, yes. I will give it a try if I have any issues, but I already solved the problem using the shell module after all - turned out to be a bit neater than expected. I will add it as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Solved by obtaining the missing group_replication.so file (I got it from MySQL Community Edition), then provisioning and enabling it using these two Ansible tasks:

```
- name: Provision the MySQL group_replication plugin
  copy:
    src: group_replication.so
    dest: /usr/lib/mysql/plugin/group_replication.so
    mode: 0644

- name: Install MySQL plugin group_replication
  shell: >
         mysql -u root -e "SHOW PLUGINS\G" | grep -q group_replication
         && echo -n FOUND
         || mysql -u root -e "INSTALL PLUGIN group_replication SONAME 'group_replication.so';"
  register: plugin_state
  changed_when: plugin_state.stdout != 'FOUND'
```

The plugin itself I placed under a local files/ folder for Ansible to find.